# Remove ">" sign in Python Django Form Label

Tags: python, forms, django-forms, label

The result from the code below is something like this:

Name:

Field for name

"> Email", but without the "-signs, but including the >-sign

Field for email

Why is there a "> " before "Email" and how do I remove it?

The code I am using is the following:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=100)
```

contact.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!-- The Contact Modal -->
<div id="contactModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="full_name" placeholder="Your name.." {{ form.full_name }}>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="from_email" placeholder="Your email.." {{ form.from_email
                            }}>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You're not closing the input elements

Comment: Yes, I do. There are <input .....> on both lines.

Comment: To close an XML element, you need to wrap it in **two** tags; i.e. `<foo>...</foo>`. Or, if your element is empty, you can write shorthand `<foo/>`. Writing just `<input attributes>content` is wrong